# Applying arithmetic operators to lists of values

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have list(s) of values and I want to apply an arithmetic operator to each value. For a binary operator like addition, this would mean something like this:

```
add_lists([],[],[]).
add_lists([A|TA],[B|TB],[R|TR]) :- R is A+B,
                                   add_lists(TA,TB,TR).
```

Now I wanted to write something like:

```
?- arithop_lists(+,[1,2,3],[0.2,-2,100],R).
```

This works:

```
arithop_lists(_Op,[],[],[]).
arithop_lists(Op,[A|TA],[B|TB],[R|TR]) :- E =.. [A,Op,B], R is E,
                                          arithop_lists(Op,TA,TB,TR).
```

But I am extremely frustrated that I couldn't find an easier way to do this. I couldn't come up with a `findall` solution that doesn't use `member`. What is more, I couldn't figure out how to do it without a `=..` call for every pair of operands.

My initial feeling was that it can be done with `maplist`, and I know it can be done, but I don't know if using `maplist` and `lambda` is any less of a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better way, efficiency wise, should be

```
add(A, B, C) :- C is A + B.
mul(A, B, C) :- C is A * B.
```

yields

```
?- X = add, maplist(X, [1,2,3], [0.2,-2,100], R).
X = add,
R = [1.2, 0, 103].

?- X = mul, maplist(X, [1,2,3], [0.2,-2,100], R).
X = mul,
R = [0.2, -4, 300].
```

*edit* library([apply_macros](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/apply_macros.pl)) could be the blueprint for efficient evaluation (via rewriting). A library of numerical algorithms could use it to get the maximal efficiency. Of course, such *optimizations* should be postponed after *correctness*.

Comment: Yes, so this ends up with me defining a predicate for each arithmetic function, I can even say `+(A,B,R) :- R is A+B` if I don't want to come up with new words. I was hoping there is an easy way for defining predicates for arithmetic functions on the fly. I also thought such predicates exist; why don't they? (I am sure there is a very good reason)

Comment: [apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.9%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/metacall.html%27%29%29)/2 could fit your needs. But for fixed arity call/4 should do.

Comment: I am that thick so be patient... I know I can write `A=1, B=2, call(is, X, A+B).` but I can't figure out how to construct the expression `A+B` out of A, B, and for example `+` passed as an argument from the caller.

Comment: AFAIK the simpler way is =.., but you already know that. Now I'll go on to see if apply_macros can be extended.